# 'bool' is not convertible to 'uint8'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build to-do app using Xcode 6 and Swift.  I was able to run the app on Xcode 6 dp2 but after updating to dp7 I'm getting this error:

```
'bool' is not convertible to 'uint8'.
```

Here is the function with the error:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {

        **if ((segue && segue!.identifier == "showdetails") != nil)**{
            var selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

            var detailViewController:DetailViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

            detailViewController.toDoData = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row) as NSDictionary

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write that is:

```
if (segue != nil && segue!.identifier == "showdetails") {
```

but an even better way is using optional binding:

```
if let segue = segue {
    if (segue.identifier == "showdetails") {
```

Note that there are other errors about incorrect usage of optionals. This is the modified code that compiles in playground:

```
if let segue = segue {
    if (segue.identifier == "showdetails") {
        var selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath? = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath {
            var detailViewController:DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController

            detailViewController.toDoData = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row) as NSDictionary
        }
    }
}
```

`indexPathForSelectedRow` returns an optional, so you have to account for that.

Update: as pointed out by @MartinR, `segue` is no longer optional, so you can solve the problem by simply updating the function signature, and its implementation should look like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showdetails") {
        var selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath {
            var detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController                
            detailViewController.toDoData = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row) as NSDictionary
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But note that `segue` is *not* an optional parameter of `prepareForSegue()` anymore: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender: .

Comment: Thanks @MartinR - hard to keep track of which optionals are no longer optionals, not to mention forced unwrapped which are now optionals...

Answer (score 0):

First of all when I read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) what I read is :

```
func prepareForSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender sender: AnyObject?)
```

UIKit seems to be updated in Beta7 to use less optionals. So `segue` may be not optional.

Then even if your function signature is good, you are comparing a Boolean to nil.

This `(segue && segue!.identifier == "showdetails")` is a boolean. A boolean is either true or false.

And at the very end, here is the best practice to unwrap a variable :

```
if let mySafeVariable = myOptionalVariable {
    if mySafeVariable.attribute == <Whatever> {

   }
}
```

You should. No, wait, you must read the Swift free iBooks.